# Seeding my Heroku hobbydev Postgres database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

I know this has been asked a lot in the past but I am simply having no luck at all.  I have successfully pushed a simple Rails blogging application to heroku.  The trouble is my seed file that I populated using the ruby faker gem won't work even when I run `heroku run rake db:seed` or `heroku run rails db:seed`.  I don't know what else I can do at this point.  I have looked at countless other stack questions and they all say the same thing, which is to run the 2 commands I just listed.  Any suggestions? Do I need to reset my production database or something?

Edit:
Here is the seed file

```
5.times do 
    Article.create([{ 
        title: "The IT Crowd",
        body: Faker::TvShows::TheITCrowd.quote,
        status: "public",
        user_id: 2
    }])
end

5.times do 
    Article.create([{ 
        title: "Bojack Horseman",
        body: Faker::TvShows::BojackHorseman.quote,
        status: "public",
        user_id: 2
    }])
end
5.times do 
        Article.create([{ 
        title: "The Big Lebowski",
        body: Faker::Movies::Lebowski.quote,
        status: "public",
        user_id: 2
    }])
end
5.times do 
    Article.create([{ 
    title: "Recipe",
    body: Faker::Food.description,
    status: "public",
    user_id: 2
}])
end
```

Here is my article model

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
    include Visible
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    has_rich_text :body
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }
  end
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What happens when you run them, it just fails with no error?  If so that makes me suspect something wrong in the seed file where the saves fail.  Could you post the seed file code? It might also help to mention any validations going on.

Comment: Please show the error you are getting

Comment: Currently I am getting no error.  I have added the seed file and my model above.

Comment: Does the seed work locally? Will there be clashes of unique fields when the seed file runs? Are you trying to seed an empty database or not? All these can make a difference.

Comment: Yeah it works locally and no crashes that I know of.  My postgres heroku database should currently be empty.

Comment: Can you try adding a bang(`!`) to your create calls. Like `Article.create!(...)` and see if any errors appear? The bang should throw a visible runtime error if something is failing. Also, have you looked at your application logs to see what is coming up when the seed command runs?

Comment: Okay I was able to figure it out.  The issue was that in my heroku deployment I did not yet have 2 users but in my seed file I was assigning all of the articles to user #2.

Comment: You can just use `Article.create( title: "Recipe", ...` here. There is absolutely no point in passing an array with just one hash.  ' That would only make sense if you used `Article.create(5.times.map { { title: "Recipe", ...  } } )` to pass an actual array of hashes.

Comment: @Jasper. When I have encountered this it has always been something like you described where the record fails to save for some reason, but you get no error output.  One thing I do to try to figure it out if I can't is use `puts` statements in the file so I can see what data the records contain and where the file might actually be failing.  Glad you got it figured out.